# Slack's `file.size` API field is sometimes wrong

Tags: slack, slack-api

In working on [wayslack](https://github.com/wolever/wayslack) I noticed that sometimes the file size reported by Slack's API doesn't match the actual size of the file in the `url_private` field. Specifically, out of the 575 files in my archive, the size on 10 of them appears to be incorrect:

```
actual size 147 != expected size 2220: .../200kdashboard-dashboard
actual size 23420 != expected size 24387: .../user_counts.tsv
actual size 1677 != expected size 1028: .../Bubble_sheets.txt
actual size 305030 != expected size 264211: .../slack_for_ios_upload.jpg
actual size 1924237 != expected size 1854941: .../slack_for_ios_upload.jpg
actual size 147 != expected size 2783: .../akindiroadmap
actual size 2245894 != expected size 2301275: .../slack_for_ios_upload.jpg
actual size 223969 != expected size 40395: .../cv_basic.pdf
actual size 224568 != expected size 2634830: .../portfolio.pdf
actual size 1953523 != expected size 1892191: .../image_uploaded_from_ios.jpg
```

Where the "actual size" is the size returned both in the `Content-Length` header of the HTTP request *and* the size of the file on disk (ie, the difference most likely isn't related to compressed HTTP responses or something).

What's going on? Why would the file sizes be different?